# sshd: User <username> not allowed because shell zsh does not exist

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to login to my PC with ssh, but every time ssh says `Permission denied (publickey).` and `/var/log/auth.log` contains entries saying:

```
Jan 16 00:00:35 DerKonig sshd[11573]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 51482 on 127.0.0.1 port 22
Jan 16 00:00:35 DerKonig sshd[11573]: User <username> not allowed because shell zsh does not exist
Jan 16 00:00:35 DerKonig sshd[11573]: input_userauth_request: invalid user <username> [preauth]
Jan 16 00:00:35 DerKonig sshd[11573]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 51482 [preauth]
```

I know for a fact that:

- User  exists.
- The `zsh` is installed.
- `/etc/shells` contains `/bin/zsh`

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/nabeel/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Does the login shell field for <username> in /etc/passwd actually say `/bin/zsh` - or just `zsh`? (You can check for example with `getent passwd <username>`)

Comment: @steeldriver: `/etc/passwd` says `zsh` and `/etc/shells ` says `/bin/zsh`

Comment: So can you access the box as another user who has sudo rights? if so, `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh <username>` should fix it, I think?

Comment: @steeldriver: Thank you so much, it worked! Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments, it turned out that while `/etc/shells` contained `/bin/zsh`, the user's login shell as specified in `/etc/passwd` was just `zsh`

Fixing the issue was then just a matter of changing the user's login shell to include the full path:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh <username>
```